# AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show dropdown, got warning

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an *ArrayList with 60-70 elements* in it. I set an adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView as follows.

```
AutoCompleteTextView  mRecipient = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.recipient);
        mRecipient.setThreshold(1);
        Log.i("Array list", ""+names);// Here I got the arrayList
        ArrayAdapter<String> nameadapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyClass.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        mRecipient.setAdapter(nameadapter);
```

But the dropdown list doesn't show up and I got some **warning**(Not errror) in Logcat.

```
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093): An exception occured during performFiltering()!
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:437)
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093):    at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 17:15:53.017: W/Filter(15093):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Also I have a ListView below this, which is empty now.

Can anybody figure out what this warning means?

Comment: Make sure `names` is not null

Comment: Actually, make sure that none of the items in `names` is `null`.

Comment: `names` is not null, but there is null items inside the list. Is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot. null values inside the list was the problem.
@vikram I can verify if you post the answer.

Comment: @Nizam no problem man, posted the suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning comes from the following code snippet in `ArrayAdapter.performFiltering(CharSequence)`:

```
 String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();  // entered by user
 final ArrayList<T> values = mOriginalValues;
 final int count = values.size();
 final ArrayList<T> newValues = new ArrayList<T>(count); // this will be returned
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     final T value = values.get(i);                      // in your case, 'value' is null at times
     final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();  // the warning

     // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
     if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
         newValues.add(value);
     } else {
         final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
         final int wordCount = words.length;
         for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
             if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                 newValues.add(value);
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

So, check for `null` values in `names`.